# Prevent textbox from losing focus when mouse leaves

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, focus

When typing/highlighting in a textbox, it loses focus immediately upon moving the mouse out of it. How do I prevent this? I only want it to lose focus if I'm clicking on another control mainly.

I hooked up the `LostFocus` event, just not sure what to put in it:

```
private void TB_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Is there a better way than looping through every other control to check if they have focus, than reassigning focus to the textbox if none of them have it?

Comment: `TB.Focus();`  ?

Comment: Are you sure its losing `focus` and not losing its `hover` state? check with `document.activeElement` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement

Comment: @FrancisLeigh WinForms.

Comment: A WinForms TextBox will not lose focus by simply moving a mouse.  You have something else going on.

Comment: Hmm, well the debugger is hitting the breakpoint I have in the LostFocus function. Literally all's I do is click the textbox, move the mouse and it instantly loses focus. I didn't think this was the default behavior, but then again I haven't used winforms in awhile.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad welp that seems to work fine. Sticking with that, thanks!

Comment: You should read about [Control.LostFocus Event - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx). Specifically, the **Caution** part.

Comment: Hmm, well in that case I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. I haven't had this trouble when working with WPF. I don't recall having this problem with textboxes in Winforms years ago.